# How do I get the user details from a JWT authentication with node and express?

Tags: postgresql, jwt, sequelize.js

After following many many tutorials that didn't work (grrr...) I've finally got JWT authentication working. I can add a user, and then log in using Postman and get a JWT string. I can add that to my header and return values from the database. Yay!

However, while this will let me authenticate users to use the site, it doesn't restrict content (yet). And this is my challenge...

Given a JWT string, how do I get the user id of the user it relates to, so I can pass that in my SQL query and restrict the results based on user?

Right now, the below works:

```
router.get('/log', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}), function(req, res) {
  var token = getToken(req.headers);
  if (token) {
    db.sequelize.query(`
        SELECT * FROM json_log(:vuserId)
        `,
        {
          replacements: {vuserId: req.body.vuserId},
          type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
        }
    )
      .then((changes) => res.status(200).send(changes))
      .catch((error) => { res.status(400).send(error); });
  } else {
    return res.status(403).send({success: false, msg: 'Unauthorized.'});
  }
});
```

If I pass the following in the body of the get request:

```
{
  "vuserId": 1
}
```

But given I'm passing the JWT in the header, surely this can tell me what the user id is?

Comment: I guess there are couple of good method for it, but one way is that you need to include the userinfo into the jwt payload when you issue the token, and when you receive the token again you can extract that userinfo again.

Comment: Ok, after more searching I found the answer.

I added 'npm install atob', then put the following at the top of the page:

```javascript
const atob = require('atob');
```

and added the following line after the 'if (token) {' line:

```javascript
var decodedValue = JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]))
```

I could then reference 'decodedValue.id' in place of the '1' in the body of the request.

Comment: If you've found an answer post an answer and accept it, not a comment and an edited title--this is discussed in the FAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after more searching I found the answer. I added 'npm install atob', then put the following at the top of the page: javascript const atob = require('atob'); and added the following line after the 'if (token) {' line: javascript var decodedValue = JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1])) I could then reference 'decodedValue.id' in place of the '1' in the body of the request.